# PHP bitcoin publickey to bitcoin address

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcoind

Is there some library / easy way to calculate the bitcoin address for a given publickey?

Can this be done by bitcoind (running in the background already)?

For example:

Pubkey (HEX): 02ee635c93f16db010ade0e1524bfc8585cea90df9cd1b1954f059b6f73be97ccb

Address: 1FMtwerNkho7MB52UXXP7VSn1VsiJHagY4

Library I found (but it seems like pubkey -> address is not supported by this lib):

https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php

Comment: Check function `testFromOutputScriptSuccess` in https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php/blob/master/tests/Address/AddressTest.php

Answer (score 0):

try this example how you can calculate the Bitcoin address from a given public key using the same  library:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Address\PayToPubKeyHashAddress;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Crypto\EcAdapter\Secp256k1\PublicKey;
use BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer;

$publicKeyHex = '02ee635c93f16db010ade0e1524bfc8585cea90df9cd1b1954f059b6f73be97ccb';

$publicKeyBuffer = Buffer::hex($publicKeyHex);
$publicKey = new PublicKey($publicKeyBuffer);

$address = new PayToPubKeyHashAddress($publicKey->getPubKeyHash());

echo "Bitcoin Address: " . $address->getAddress() . "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

This library has that you want:

```
PublicKeyFactory::fromHex($data) - Parses PublicKeyInterface from hex string or Buffer
```